# Почему «джоуль», но «Дж»?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, сокращения

Можете, совы, сказать, почему мы пишем ***Дж*** с большой буквы, несмотря на тот-с факт, что ***джоуль*** — как видно — мы пишем с маленькой таки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Страница из [Википедии](https://info.wikireading.ru/655):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поэтому и с прописной.

Answer (score 1):

Если Джоуль - то это фамилия. А если дж -  то это вообще непонятно что, потому что в честь Джоуля называна единица, но несокращенные единицы измерения по-русски пишут с маленькой буквы как имена нарицательные или вроде того.